# App Engine startup & logging woes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

After finally getting my "Hello World" web app working in the App Engine development server I've uploaded it to the cloud and immediately struck problems.

(The first problem is that my app takes longer than 30s to start up; I'm using Armed Bear Common Lisp (ABCL) on the JVM and my app pulls in quite a bit of code. I mention this not to ask for help (and I'm not getting "timeout" exceptions) but in case it has any bearing on the other problems described below.)

The next problem is that I'm not seeing my `java.util.logging.Logger` log messages (from either my Java or Lisp code) in the App Engine console. I've set `.level=FINER` in my `logging.properties` file but I don't see any of the messages I see using the development server, apart from a single `INFO`-level message saying `Startup completed in -0.001 seconds.`, sent to `stdout`.

The other message I do see is an exception from my code, which suggests that either the servlet's `init` method hasn't been called or it couldn't read the `context-param` values from the `web.xml` file (via `GenericServlet.getInitParameter()`). I've added `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to my `web.xml` file but this hasn't helped. I'm wondering whether I should've used `system-properties` in my `appengine-web.xml` file instead of `context-param` elements in `web.xml`. (I'm now checking both, to no apparent  effect.) But I could debug this if I had my log messages.

In the same log message as the exception there is also the text `javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable` which must be a clue, but Google doesn't throw up any obvious leads for it.

I have added a dirt-simple "Hello World" servlet to my application that calls `log.severe()` and `log.info()` to try and get any log messages to appear in the [Google Cloud Platform Console Log Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) (or the legacy [AppEngine Log Viewer](https://appengine.google.com/logs)). On running this I don't get the `log: unavailable` message but I don't get any log messages either.

I can't help the feeling I'm missing something obvious. Where do people go to see their Java log messages in the Google Cloud Platform Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out my logging problem. The [Oracle Java 7 docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#global) to use `Logger.getGlobal()` but the Google `java-docs-samples` code uses `Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName())`. I was using the former which fails silently.

It would be nice if this was documented somewhere, or if any of the code snippets in the documentation actually used log messages.

Comment: I've submitted a documentation update request for https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging.